# Devise resource and resource_name helpers in custom controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, helper

I extended the default Devise RegistrationsController using routes:

```
# use my own controller for devise registrations
devise_for :users, :controllers => { registrations: 'registrations' }
```

In this controller, I have a method called **new_from_invitation**. This method renders a custom signup form to display in case the user comes from an invitation.

I copied the file devise/registrations/new.html.erb. So my custom signup form looks like this:

```
<%= form_for(resource, :as => resource_name, :url => registration_path(resource_name)) do |f| %>
```

This throws an ArgumentError because resource is nil. Same as resource name.
Somehow, the resource and resource_name helpers are available in the default devise/registrations/new method but I can't figure out how. And therefore can't figure out a way to have these helpers available for my custom method.
Any help would be very much appreciated!

Answer (score 7):

Add this to your Application helper file :

```
  def resource_name
    :user
  end

  def resource
    @user ||= User.new
  end
  def devise_mapping
    @devise_mapping ||= Devise.mappings[:user]
  end
```

Comment: Hey, Thanks for your reply. Actually i've already got these lines in ApplicationHelper. And it doesn't seem to work..

Comment: I just got it working by adding: **helper ApplicationHelper::ApplicationHelper** at the top of RegistrationsController. But this doesn't feel right. Shouldn't the controller automatically see the Helper's methods?

Comment: The error I was getting was **First argument in form cannot contain nil or be empty**

Comment: Helper methods are not directly available in controller, you will have to include them, but application helpers methods are available in view.

Comment: Actually I want to use them in the view, not in the controller. So they should be available shouldn't they?